# Designing app to load a UIViewController/SpriteKit app without going through XCode and interface builder?

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit, uikit, theos

Is it possible to create a SpriteKit game without the main storyBoard that get created by the interface builder ?
Because I'm using theos to make apps and it doesn't have an interface builder so everything have to be done by code

Comment: I changed your tags to help with your results a little better,  You are more focused on getting UIViewController working first, that is a part of UIKit.  After that is in place,  getting to use Sprite-Kit should be a lot easier

Comment: Thanks you helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. You will just need to add all the views and sprites, etc in code, but it is possible.

Comment: Any idea how I'm still a newbie

Comment: All i need is the code to add to the appDelegate  to init the view